# Master/Detail: Casting and binding with IEnumerable and IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following Master/Detail scenario which is populated through a linq query:

```
    Public Class MasterDto
        Public Property ANYMASTERVALUE1 As String
        Public Property DETAILDTO() As IEnumerable(Of DetailDto)
    End Class

    Public Class DetailDto
        Public Property ANYDETAILVALUE1 As String
        Public Property ANYDETAILVALUE2 As String
    End Class

    Dim query = From a In db.TABLE1
                Select New MasterDto With {
                  .ANYMASTERVALUE1 = a.ANYMASTERVALUE1,
                  .DETAILDTO = From b In db.TABLE2
                               Where a.ID = b.ID
                               Select New MasterDto With {
                                 .ANYDETAILVALUE1 = b.ANYDETAILVALUE1,
                                 .ANYDETAILVALUE2 = b.ANYDETAILVALUE2
                                }
                }
```

**1st Problem**

When query multiple records and then try to call a `query = query.toList` I get the following Error:

Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

But when I change the `Public Property DETAILDTO() As IEnumerable(Of DetailDto)` to `Public Property DETAILDTO() As IQueryable(Of DetailDto)` everything works fine.

*Is there a way to use the IEnumerable(Of ...) because if I can't use it I run into a second error.*

**2nd Problem**

I just could use IQueryable, but the I run into my 2nd problem. 
I extend the query to get a single record `Where a.ID = 123` and then use a View to display the master data and a Html.EditorFor template for the detail data like so:

View

```
@ModelType MvcApp.MasterDto
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ANYMASTERVALUE1)
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DETAILDTO)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
End Using
```

EditorFor

```
@ModelType MvcApp.PostMedienDto
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ANYDETAILVALUE1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ANYDETAILVALUE2)
```

On the HttpPost (klicking the save button) when I use the `Public Property DETAILDTO() As IEnumerable(Of DetailDto)` in my Master DTO I get the following exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

When I Use `Public Property DETAILDTO() As IEnumerable(Of DetailDto)` the Model (master and detail data) binds correctly and gets returned to the conroller.

I hope you see my dilemma and have a solution?

Comment: you should use Collection<T> or List<T>. The binder cannot materialize an interface, probably because he can determine which type to use.

Comment: Thanks, but this will still give me the `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types`error when returnung multiple records as mentioned under Problem 1

Comment: Is there any reason that the association isn't defined in the model?

Comment: I'm not shure what you mean?